# Duplicate Symbols tutorial IOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am an intermediate programmer and new to Objective-C and X-Code. I have a sense on what duplicate symbols error means in general, that is having a duplicate class, or variable somewhere in my code. I tried to follow the appcoda tutorials and I am stuck on this duplicate symbols error. I am using Xcode 6, the tutorials sometimes are deprecated but this isn't the  the case. I followed this example like many others step by step, however I can't get my own code to work.

[image: here is a screenshot of the error I get]

I would like to understand once and for all, why do I get this error, not only in IOS but in other languages as well, since everything seems fine. I hope this screenshot will be helpful to get my question solved, and explained, if you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: May you open "project navigator" and type "RecipeCollectionHeaderView" into search string? How many results can you see? only RecipeCollectionHeaderView.h and RecipeCollectionHeaderView.m or few of them?

Comment: May you add screenshot of results into your question?

Comment: I see 4. I would gladly attach a screenshot if I knew how. I am new in here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 files. You must cut/rename two of them. Better to add some prefix(read bellow). You can have only 1 class with unique name(because you don't have namespaces in ObjC) => You can have only one ".h" file and only one ".m" file. So you have to use prefixes.

I am not sure, but may be it will help you to solve your problem once and for all.

[Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)

In order to keep class names unique, the convention is to use prefixes on all classes. You’ll have noticed that Cocoa and Cocoa Touch class names typically start either with NS or UI. Two-letter prefixes like these are reserved by Apple for use in framework classes. As you learn more about Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, you’ll encounter a variety of other prefixes that relate to specific frameworks:

NS Foundation (OS X and iOS) and Application Kit (OS X)

UI UIKit (iOS)

AB Address Book

CA Core Animation

CI Core Image

Comment: Umm, thank you I will keep that in mind, but this doesn't seem to solve my problem, since it's not about the class, the class is indeed unique, on the other hand the keyword that generates the error above is used all around this project and it seems I have miss used it somehow. Here is a more detailed description. If it is a must I'll attach screenshots with the entire code. http://s17.postimg.org/ss6t1l38v/screenshot_detailed.png